# ActionScript 3 - Using CASALIB Distribution for several objects with different sizes

Tags: actionscript-3, distribution

Does anyone know of a framework similar to CASALIB that has some class  Distribution of objects with different sizes?

I'm using the Distribution class, but it only works for objects with similar sizes.

See [this link](http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_layout_Distribution.html)

Comment: what about extending the class?

Answer (score 0):

I am building a pure actionscript ui/layout framework. [here](http://quui.de/layout/) is a demo so you can check whether it fits your requirements. If it does, the [source is here](https://bitbucket.org/maxmc/uitoolkit/src/1a5904f539c0/src/org/splink/guitoolkit/layout/).